# CMD, Path not filename

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I am working with a VB.net project. I was using the command promt (cmd).
I told the CMD to do: Copy /b path1 + path2 destination

However the cmd thought my path was a FileName.
So how do i tell cmd that it is a path and not FileName.

//Thank you!

PS. the path are not the same so i could not use for example: CD C:\mydocs\

Comment: What does this have to do with VB.Net?

Comment: I "inject" commands to the cmd

Comment: **You should not be using CMD for this**.  _Use `File.Copy`!_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put a `\` at the end of the path to show `copy` that it's a directory.

**EDIT**: You need to put your path in quotes (`"..."`) to force the shell's argument parser to pass the entire path as one.

Comment: YE smart. But i was dumb not saying that the path was a filepath :( Example C:\Hello\firstcopy.txt

Comment: I have no idea what you're saying.

Comment: I got spaces in my filepath.(c:\hello world\t.txt)
The CMD reacts on the space between hello and world and think that world is the destination

Answer (score 1):

Don’t use the command prompt for that, use the [`System.IO.File.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6cfw35a.aspx) method of the .NET framework instead.

… obviously, the same goes for other methods that exist in the framework. If you don’t know whether a certain method exists, try searching the MSDN.

Comment: But in this case i am using the CMD :) Okej. i wanna stick with that. But thank you for the tip. But any other idea?